# Custom sort with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, sorting, google-sheets, re2

I have two columns, first with a list of names and second with their rating. I want to use custom sort, for which I use the following (found it [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sort-by-custom-order-in-google-sheets/))
:

```
=sort(A33:B50;match(B33:B50;{"Great";"Good";"OK";"Bad");true)
```

Which works, but my ratings are actually:

- Great+
- Great
- Great-
- Good+
- Good
- Good-
- OK+
- ...

Is there any way where I can combine the formula above with regular expressions? Something along the lines of this:

```
=sort(A33:B50;match(B33:B50;{"Great*";"Good*";"OK*";"Bad*");true)
```

Which doesn't really do anything. Checked out the regex formulas of Google sheets, but couldn't find any that would do the trick in this situation.

Cheers!

PS: A workaround would be

```
=sort(A33:B50;match(B33:B50;{"Great+";"Great";"Great-";"Good+";"Good";"Good-";"OK+";"OK";"OK-";"Bad+";"Bad";"Bad-");true)
```

but I'm curious if there's a less tedious way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=sort(A1:B7;match(regexextract(B1:B7;"Great|Good|OK|Bad");{"Great";"Good";"OK";"Bad"};0);true)`

- Pipeline `|` is for OR login in Regex.
- Change `A1:B7` and `B1:B7` to your ranges.

**Edit**

- for sorting `Good+ Good Good-` change regex to `"Great|Good\+|Good\-|Good|OK|Bad"`, change the array to `{"Great";"Good+";"Good";"Good-";"OK";"Bad"}`

> counter-intuitive: the order in the regextract is Good+|Good-|Good
>   and in the array {"Great";"Good+";"Good";"Good-";"OK";"Bomb"} (Good in the regex was already capturing Good- instances)

Comment: That doesn't really sort properly (example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mxLUZqh-Zp6y-dW6G7qCRQ6pJaQP1_w1wur0rcpiZRw/edit?usp=sharing). The resulting order is: "Great
Great
Great
Good- (?)
Great
Good
Good+ (?)
Great (?)
OK
OK bit bad
OK
OK
Bad"

Comment: Sorry, I've missed 0 in the `match` function for the exact match. Please try `=sort(A1:B7;match(regexextract(B1:B7;"Great|Good|OK|Bad");{"Great";"Good";"OK";"Bad"};0);true)`

Comment: Yep, that did it. It sorts first Good-
Good
Good+ (Is there any way this can be added into the formula?). The rest of the sort works fine.

Comment: Tried what you included in the new edit and it created the order: Great Good+ Good- Good OK    Bad    (which is better than before, but still not the intended result). The formula I'm using is: =sort(A33:B50;match(regexextract(B33:B50;"Great|Good\+|Good|Good\-|OK|Bad");{"Great";"Good+";"Good";"Good-";"OK";"Bad"};0);true)

Maybe we need to select for Good without \- coming after it, so Good- won't be selected by "Good"?

Comment: Found a way to make it work:
=sort(A33:B50;match(regexextract(B33:B50;"Great|Good\+|Good\-|Good|OK|Bomb");{"Great";"Good+";"Good";"Good-";"OK";"Bomb"};0);true) which is counter-intuitive: the order in the regextract is Good\+|Good\-|Good and in the array {"Great";"Good+";"Good";"Good-";"OK";"Bomb"} (I guess Good in the regex was already capturing Good\- instances)

Comment: @jlo, thank you for the research. You're right, Good was capturing first. I've edited the answer.